# How to pass title and name in render function

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I was completely off my head when I first paused the question. Okay,
I have my navbar that links to registration page.

`<li class="nav-item cta"><a href="{% url 'register' %}" class="nav-link"><span>Get started</span></a></li>`

The registration page is rendered between the header and footer section (base template). I want to retrieve title for every page that has been rendered to the base template which has below code to handle incoming title;

```
{% if title %}
<title>{{title}}</title>
{% else %}
<title>default-title</title>
{% endif %}
```

How can I load the register page with custom title?

Comment: That error is not coming from this code, and has nothing to do with passing the title to the render function.

Comment: You're right...

Answer (score 0):

In `views.py`

```
def about(request):
    context = {
        'title': 'this is title',
        'about': 'this is about'
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html', context)
```

Then in `about.html`

```
<h1> {{ title }} </h1>
<p> {{ about }} </p>
```